# Separate watch time in one document

Tags: javascript

I found a script that counts down the time. In each script I set a different time to the end. After saving the file, the time in each element is the same. Does anyone know how to solve the time in each **`<div>`** script for each script separately?

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("April 3, 2019 01:59:59").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("clockfirst").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("clockfirst").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

I have duplicate and inserted this above code three times to one document and changed content in every script:

- clockfirst
- clocksecond
- clockthird

below script I add html tags:

```
<div id="clockfirst"></div>
<div id="clocksecond"></div>
<div id="clockthird"></div>
```

after save display the same time for each element:
[image]

@mplingjan I checked before this topic and not solve my issue, that's why I created new topic. Yes, I changed setInterval for every script and this no solve issue for me.

Comment: Tip: have a JavaScript function that creates a new `<div id="clockN">` element each time it's invoked.

Comment: can you please check my update? I created different tags <div> for each script

Comment: Did you also change `var x = setInterval` to `var y = setInterval` etc?

Comment: @mplingjan I checked before this topic and not solve my issue, that's why I created new topic. Yes, I changed setInterval for every script and this no  solve issue for me.